# Use a Service's result in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

The `Service` code here gets some items from an RSS Feed. And then generates a List of the Items. The method `getItems()` is the one that exposes what has been brought in.

```
public class RssService extends Service {

    ThisBinder mBinder = new ThisBinder();      
    private List<Item> items;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
    //Hid some code for brevity
    Log.i("items", Arrays.deepToString(items.toArray()));   
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

List<Item> getItems(){
    return items;
}



class ThisBinder extends Binder{
    RssService getService() {
        return RssService.this;
    }

}}
```

This `BroadcastReceiver` here starts the service every 15 minutes.

```
public class RssReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Long REPEAT_TIME = 15L * 60L * 1000L;
        //  Long REPEAT_TIME = 1000L;
        RssService rssService;
        IBinder binder;
        private Context mContext;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mContext = context;
            AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, StartServiceReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);               
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connected, total Items, " + rssService.getItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

I need to use the `RssService.getItems()` method here so that I can generate a notification. So far I haven't been able to do this. I can't seem to find the proper way to get an instance of the service.

How can this be done?

Comment: You should not construct services (or activities, or broadcast receivers) explicitly. The Android system does that internally. btw how abt service saves a sharedpreference key and you read from there ?

Comment: can't gain a Context instance within Service.

Comment: @twntee please detail how to use the services created by android itself?

Comment: you can get Context in service, the this keyword ! O_o